# EntityFramework mapping table wrong

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I have 2 tables:

> Categories and
>   Users

The **CategoryId** is an int and the **UserId** is a string (nvarchar(128)).
I have this mapping for my user:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.ForbiddenCategories)
    .WithMany(t => t.ForbiddenUsers)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("UserForbiddenCategories");
        m.MapLeftKey("CategoryId");
        m.MapRightKey("UserId");
    });
```

but when I create a database for this, it does this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserForbiddenCategories](
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserForbiddenCategories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [CategoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserForbiddenCategories]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserForbiddenCategories_dbo.Categories_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserForbiddenCategories] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserForbiddenCategories_dbo.Categories_UserId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserForbiddenCategories]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserForbiddenCategories_dbo.IdentityUsers_CategoryId] FOREIGN KEY([CategoryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[IdentityUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserForbiddenCategories] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserForbiddenCategories_dbo.IdentityUsers_CategoryId]
GO
```

which is completely the wrong way around. CategoryId should be the int with a FK to Categories and UserId should be the string with a FK to IdentityUsers.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or how I can tell EF to change the maps around?

Cheers,

/r3plica

Comment: Have you tried different order of the keys? It seems that "UserId" should be the left key and "CategoryId" should be the right one.

Comment: yeah, turns out in CategoryMap I had it mapping also, seems to have caused a mixup, but you are right UserId should be the left key :D silly me!